# Specify numeric field value at creation in Firestore?

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to create an integer value inside the firestore database at creation. However every variable I pass get turned into a string.

This is what I have:

```
next_group_id = self.GetNextGroupId() #returns int value
try:
# get the document
    doc_ref = self._db.collection(GROUPS).document(next_group_id)      

    # create a new document  
    # this gets created as a string in firestore    
    doc_ref.set({
        u'Group Id': next_group_id, 
    })
    print("Created Group '{}'.".format(group._group_name))
except:
    print("Possible firestore error has accord - unable to create group")
```

Comment: Does it set a number correct if you hard-code the value? I.e. `doc_ref.set({
                u'Group Id': 12, 
            })`. If so, it's at least clear that the problem is on the client/Python side.

Comment: I get this error A path element must be a string. Received 102, which is a <class 'int'>.

Comment: Hmmm... that sounds weird. I'm not sure why that happens, so hope that somebody else notices.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you cant search document with an integer like this:

```
doc_ref = self._db.collection(GROUPS).document(next_group_id)
```

So I just cast to an string and it works fine...

```
doc_ref = self._db.collection(GROUPS).document(str(next_group_id))
```